# Best way to represent part-of (mereological) transitivity for OWL classes?

Tags: owl, ontology

I have a background in frame-based ontologies, in which classes represent concepts and there's no restriction against assertion of class:class relationships.

I am now working with an OWL2 ontology and trying to determine the best/recommended way to represent "canonical part-of" relationships - conceptually, these are relationships that are true, by definition, of the things represented by each class (i.e., all instances).  The part-of relationship is transitive, and I want to take advantage of that so that I'd be able to query the ontology for "all parts of (a canonical) X".

For example, I might want to represent:

- "engine" is a part of "car", and
- "piston" is a part of "engine"

and then query transitively, using SPARQL, for parts of cars, getting back both engine and piston.  Note that I want to be able to represent individual cars later (and be able to deduce their parts by reference to their `rdf:type`), and of course I want to be able to represent sub-classes of cars as well, so I can't model the above-described classes as individuals - they must be classes.

It seems that I have 3 options using OWL, none ideal. Is one of these recommended (or are any discouraged), and am I missing any?

1. **OWL restriction axioms:**

```
rdfs:subClassOf(engine, someValuesFrom(partOf, car))
rdfs:subClassOf(piston, someValuesFrom(partOf, engine))
```

The major drawback of the above is that there's no way in SPARQL to query transitively over the partOf relationship, since it's embedded in an OWL restriction.  I would need some kind of generalized recursion feature in SPARQL - or I would need the following rule, which is not part of any standard OWL profile as far as I can tell:

**antecedent (body):**
subClassOf(B, (P some A) ^
subClassOf(C, (P some B) ^
transitiveProperty(P)

**consequent (head):**
subClassOf(C, (P some A))

2. **OWL2 punning:** I could effectively represent the partOf relationships on canonical instances of the classes, by asserting the object-property directly on the classes.  I'm not sure that that'd work transparently with SPARQL though, since the partOf relationships would be asserted on instances (via punning) and any subClassOf relationships would be asserted on classes.  So if I had, for example, a subclass `six_cylinder_engine`, the following SPARQL snippet would not bind `six_cylinder_engine`:

```
?part (rdfs:subClassOf*/partOf*)+ car
```

3. **Annotation property:** I could assert partOf as an annotation property on the classes, with values that are also classes.  I think that would work (minus transitivity, but I could recover that easily enough with SPARQL paths as in the query above), but it seems like an abuse of the intended use of annotation properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have performed a good analysis of the problem and the advantages/disadvantages of different approaches. I don't know if any one is discouraged or encouraged. IMHO this problem has not received sufficient attention, and is a bigger problem in some domains than others (I work in bio-ontologies which frequently use partonomies, and hence this is very important).

For 1, your rule is valid and justified by OWL semantics. There are other ways to implement this using OWL reasoners, as well as RDF-level reasoners. For example, using the [ROBOT](http://robot.obolibrary.org/) command line wrapper to the OWLAPI, you can run the [reason](http://robot.obolibrary.org/reason) command using an [Expression Materializing Reasoner](https://github.com/owlcollab/expression-materializing-reasoner). E.g

```
robot reason --exclude-tautologies true --include-indirect true -r emr -i engine.owl -o engine-reasoned.owl
```

This will give you an axiom `piston subClassOf partOf some car` that can be queried using a non-transitive SPARQL query.

The `--exclude-tautologies` removes inferences to `owl:Thing`, and `--include-indirect` will include transitive inferences.

For your option 2, you have to be careful in that you may introduce incorrect inferences. For example, assume there are some engines without pistons, i.e. `engine SubClassOf inverse(part_of) some piston` does *not* hold. However, in your punned shadow world, this *would* be entailed. This may or may not be a problem depending on your use case.

A variant of your 2 is to introduce different mapping rules for layering OWL T-Tboxes onto RDF, such as described in my [OWLStar](https://github.com/cmungall/owlstar) proposal. With this proposal, existentials would be mapped to direct triples, but there is another mechanism (e.g. reification) to indicate the intended quantification. This allows writing rules that are both safe (no undesired inferences) and complete (for anything expressible in OWL-RL). Here there is no punning (under the alternative RDF to OWL interpretation). You can also use the exact same transitive SPARQL query you wrote to get the desired results.

Comment: Thanks, these are helpful suggestions and I'm glad that I don't seem to be missing any obvious solutions. For the sake of simplicity and inter-operability with reasoners in off-the-shelf triple stores, I'm inclined to go with a version of my option 3, inventing a new annotation property for the purpose (canonicalPartOf). That also distinguishes the meaning ("normal fingers are part of a hand") from partOf ("this finger is part of that hand"), which seems appropriate.